# Setting global variables, functions in cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I wonder if its possible to set up for example variable with function for login on global level in cypress.
So I could for example on start of every test write " login; " and then just continue from when I am already inside app.

Same thing for " logout;" function.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve login persistence using the `cy.session()` command.

From the example documentation,

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.session('login', () => {
    cy.visit('/login')
    cy.get('[data-test=name]').type(name)
    cy.get('[data-test=password]').type('s3cr3t')
    cy.get('form').contains('Log In').click()
    cy.url().should('contain', '/login-successful')
  })
})
```

Put this code into `cypress/support/e2e.js` to ensure it runs before every test in every spec (when using the `cacheAcrossSpecs=true` option in configuration).

**NOTE** the login only performs once, `cy.session()` manages the **stored credentials** automatically for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by using cypress custom commands. Here is the doc - https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html

You can create custom commands under `cypress/support/commands.js`

An example from the cypress doc of how a login function can look like:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('typeLogin', (user) => {
  cy.get('input[name=email]')
    .type(user.email)

  cy.get('input[name=password]')
    .type(user.password)
})
```

Now in the tests, you use the above custom command as:

```
cy.typeLogin({ email: 'fake@email.com', password: 'Secret1' })
```